# viper-next-line, viper-previous-line has trouble with visual-line-mode?

Tags: emacs, viper, viper-mode, vimpulse

Anyone else have any trouble with `j` and `k` in viper-mode `when visual-line-mode` is enabled? It skips many lines... is there any harm in re-binding them to `next-line` and `previous-line`, which recognizes visual "line breaks" in Emacs > version 23?

Answer (score 1):

I rarely ever use this.

If you ever need to go up/down visual-line-wise, you can always use g j, g k (in Vimpulse, since you've tagged this question with Vimpulse), which is, at any rate, faster than C-n / C-p.

Comment: C-n / C-p will always be faster than g j, g k.
Try it: hold the Ctrl key, and then hit n or p repeatedly.  Now try the same with g j and g k; not only do you need more keypresses but you have to worry about sequencing them properly

Comment: You're right, Huy. I meant easier on the fingers... My fingers hurt with C-n / C-p. :-) Btw, the default behaviour is really helpful in modes like org-mode, or even general programming language modes, where you can zip down quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I also want the same thing.

So in .emacs, I remapped:

```
(vimpulse-map "k" 'previous-line)
(vimpulse-map "j" 'next-line)
(vimpulse-map "gk" 'viper-previous-line)
(vimpulse-map "gj" 'viper-next-line)
(vimpulse-map [(up)] 'viper-previous-line)
(vimpulse-map [(down)] 'viper-next-line)
(vimpulse-map "0" 'vimpulse-beginning-of-visual-line)
(vimpulse-map "$" 'vimpulse-end-of-visual-line)
(vimpulse-map "g0" 'viper-beginning-of-line)
(vimpulse-map "g$" 'viper-goto-eol)
```

In my .vimrc, I remapped:

```
noremap k gk
noremap j gj
noremap gk k
noremap gj j
noremap 0 g0
noremap ^ g^
noremap $ g$
noremap g0 0
noremap g^ ^
noremap g$ $
```